# Blazor Cascading Parameter

Tags: parameters, blazor, cascading

Lets say I have a Blazor component that accepts Cascading Value like this:

```
<CascadingValue Value="true">
  <SomeComponent/>
<CascadingValue/>
```

Now in my code, if I navigate to this component, how do I provide the CascadingValue?

```
public void SomeEvent()
{
   NavigationManger.NavigateTo("somecomponent");
}
```

How do I pass the CascadingValue in this case?

Comment: I think you might be missing the purpose of cascading values/parameters.  They are intended to pass data down your component tree.  [Documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) "Cascading values and parameters provide a convienent way to flow data down a component hierarchy from an ancestor component to any number of decendent components."  Page navigation is orthogonal to cascading parameters.

Comment: Note there is a difference between a CascadingValue and a CascadingParameter. Don't confuse them.

Comment: Listen, we are not robots, we are humans...You can at least thank me.

Comment: You are always welcome. Always great feedback. A bundle of  thanks!